# Sql query plan taking forever to create for simple query

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a simple query that should take <= 1 second. It is taking forever, which is unexpected and just started happening last week. I turned on the query plan to find that it's taking that 10 minutes to come up with the query plan for this simple query. It just ran in 9:30 and 9:29 of that was the query plan. It returns <4k rows from tables with not too many more records than that.

Any ideas on what could be causing the query plan to suddenly take forever?

I don't think the query is relevant as it is doing the same thing on several different queries. The machine has been restarted, all patches applied, etc. I still am seeing insane time taken to create a query plan for what is not much more than a select top 1000. It seems that once it figures it out, it subsequently runs faster/ almost normal. But any new query again takes much longer than it should. I would appreciate any tips on what to look at or how to fix.

I tried to run a query and was expecting it to take 1-5 seconds and it's taking 10 minutes.

Edit:
I was comparing to a select top 1000 from a table. I had a very simple one with about 2 joins to 2 other small tables that was taking a a long time, so I knew it wasn't just an ugly query. Once the execution plan is calculated it doesn't take a ton of time thereafter.

I have a slightly more complex one that ran in <1 second last week and is taking 9:30 today. Execution plan here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1CxfNUeh.

When I re-run it I can't re-create the same results. It runs in 3 seconds once the execution plan has been created. It just seems to take forever for it to figure out the execution plan.

Comment: "select top 1000" from what? A table or a view? Any trace flags enabled? What `@@version`? Are you able to share any of these plans with long compile time to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/? Has compatibility level been changed on database so you are getting different cardinality estimator?

Comment: What is the actual query? Could you be suffering parameter sniffing?

Comment: The execution plan you posted has three statements in it. They have compile times of 0ms , 7ms and 42ms - and elapsed times of 0ms, 98ms and 102 ms so no where near 9 minutes (but all plans were retrieved from cache)

Comment: Maybe it is (re)building statistics on your tables. Not sure why that part would take so long, but hard to see how large your tables are

Comment: @siggemannen - you can see that by looking at `TableCardinality` in the XML

Comment: @Martin Smith - those compile times sound about right. And I think when it actually runs it does it that fast, but it takes 9+ minutes to figure out that it's going to do that. But that's odd that they were retrieved from cache and it did take that long. I made sure I grabbed the plan that took 9:30 to render. I wonder if it could have an issue accessing the cache, or something else?

Comment: The original execution plan that took a long time to compile could have been lost because there was a statement level recompile. It could have been the initial one when the batch was compiled. So generating the estimated execution plans may show the issue better. If you are able to do see this issue when it takes a long time to generate an estimated plan then look at the compile times for the statements in the plan and see what they look like (and if bloated estimated row counts)

Answer (score 1):

The execution plan you posted doesn't show long compile times but the plan was retrieved from cache.

The execution plan for your query 3 does reference a table, `#Membership`, twice and a table `#Participation` 13 times and both of these tables have zero rows (`TableCardinality="0"`).

I did [recently encounter an issue](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/321839/3690) with long compile times for a query joining empty tables myself. It seems the new cardinality estimator can get the estimated row counts very wrong in this type of case and end up spending far too long trying to find cheaper plans as a result.

You can try adding a `OPTION (USE HINT ('FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION'));` query hint to get that query to use the legacy cardinality estimator

Comment: Thank you! I will try that. Both of those are temp tables that are populated within the query itself, but it makes sense that the plan would have them empty prior to it running and populating them.

Comment: @DaniCalifornia - has the database compatibility level recently been changed? Or have you installed any updates lately? I'm not sure why this would just suddenly become an issue

Comment: We installed updates and a patch the other day, after this became an issue. It's Sql server 19.0.2. We did upgrade to 19 a little while ago, but it was not an issue after upgrade and it is an issue now, as of ~4 days ago. I feel like something must be broken or hanging somewhere.